# Making a 5 V to 4.2 (or 3.7) V output converter with an output current of 500 mA?

Tags: voltage-regulator, esp32, adafruit

I currently have a 5 V source that outputs a nominal current of 1.5 A. I want to be able to convert it to 4.2 V or 3.7 V with a current of 500 mA to power a Adafruit HUZZAH32 - ESP32 Feather, which can be powered between 4.2/3.7 V via the BAT pin.

What is a circuit that I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to do this, you can directly power it from your 5V supply using the VBUS pins (JP3 pin 3). The board already includes the necessary power management circuitry to generate the 3.3V module supply from 5V USB (or any other 5V) input.

Comment: It will also work with 5V on VBAT if there is no battery installed. Schematics https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/assets/assets/000/041/630/original/feather_schem.png

Comment: I was looking at the data sheet and found the USB pin. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 3):

You would use a regulator circuit. Since the current required and the voltage difference is low, a low dropout linear regulator would work. A step down or buck switching regulator would work as well. Worst case you could use a 1n4001 or similar diode to drop it down the nominal 0.7V of its forward voltage drop.

But you don't need a separate circuit. The board you want already has a linear regulator for this, a AP2112-3.3. It brings 5v usb on VUSB or the 4.2 to 3.x of a lipo battery on VBAT down to 3.3V that the microcontroller uses natively.

Per the schematic, both VBAT and VUSB feed into the regulator.